# I want to change the wallpaper of my pc but it becomes black instead

Tags: python, winapi

```
import ctypes
path = 'pic.jpg'
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20 , 0 , path , 0)
```

what happens is that my current wallpaper changes into black colour , instead i want to change it to the desired picture.

Comment: That's a relative path. How is Windows supposed to know where to look for that file?

Comment: [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa): *"When the `SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER` flag is used, `SystemParametersInfo` returns `TRUE` unless there is an error (like when the specified file doesn't exist)."* Checking return values is mandatory. Besides, when changing system parameters, you'll want to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message. This is controlled through the fourth parameter. It's also questionable whether `path` uses the correct character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your ctypes syntax looks fine, so the problem is likely with your `path` variable.

Try replacing `'pic.jpg'` with the absolute path of the picture (i.e., including the directories) and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that your path is valid, try to use an absolute path and add the [`SPIF_SENDCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa#parameters) flag.

```
import ctypes
path = 'D:\\test\\pic.jpg'
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20 , 0 , path , 2) #SPIF_SENDCHANGE value is 0x0002
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# yes, you can change using python library ctypes.
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
path_to_wallpaper = r'C:\python\friday.jpg'            
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path_to_wallpaper , 0)
```